# CartoDB Toggle Map View?

Tags: carto-js

I am trying to follow this tutorial that has buttons to toggle (all points are on the same layer)

[CartoDB Toggle map tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html)

I try to follow as close I can for my own purpose but I always get the error under line 71 "uncaught reference Error: layer is not defined" (see attached screen shot)

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? I tried messing around with all the Layers, Sublayers, layer, sublayer...but non worked.

Here is the script

beginning of script tag

```
var layerUrl = 'my cartodb url';
    var sublayers = [];

  function main() {
    cartodb.createVis('map', layerUrl, {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: true,
        tiles_loader: true,
        center_lat: 22.273904,
        center_lon: 114.174510,
        zoom: 14
    })


    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      layers[1].setInteraction(true);
      layers[1].on('featureOver', function(e, pos, latlng, data) {
        cartodb.log.log(e, pos, latlng, data);


      });

      map = vis.getNativeMap();

        var subLayerOptions = {
  sql: "SELECT * FROM final_landreclamation_all" }
        var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(1);
            sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);
            sublayers.push(sublayer);


    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    var LayerActions = {
all: function(){
  sublayers[1].setSQL("SELECT * FROM final_landreclamation_all");
  return true;
},
Saiwan: function(){
  sublayers[1].setSQL("SELECT * FROM final_landreclamation_all where district_en = 'Saiwan'");
  return true;
},
Sheungwan: function() {
  sublayers[1].set({
    sql: "SELECT * FROM final_landreclamation_all where district_en = 'Sheungwan'",
  });
  return true;
}
```

}
    $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.button').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

```
LayerActions[$(this).attr('id')]();
```

});

```
  }

  window.onload = main;

end of script tag
```

[image: Screen Shot]